# How do I update a subsection inside a div block after HTML inside of that div block gets overwritten by a trigger() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, eventtrigger

I have a situation where my trigger() event overwrites a DIV with new data.

I want to create an event where *after* div is overwritten with data, the inner portion of that div displays a message that "update has been completed"

How can I do this?  Please see code for details - see comments in the code for clarity.

**Desired Outcome**

User clicks "Update" button, and sees text "Value Updated", which is currently not shown.

```js
$("#item_id").on("change", function(e) {
  $("#response_area1").html("Changed to :" + this.value);


});


$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
  $('#item_id').trigger('change');

  /*
   * I want to display "Value Updated" AFTER the above 
   * trigger event has completed.  How?
   */
  $("#response_area2").html("Value Updated");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <select id="item_id">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="form2">

  <button id="submit">Update</button>
</form>

<div id="response_area1">

  <div id="response_area2"></div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<div id="response_area">
</div>
```

Comment: is it important that `response_area2` is a child of `response_area1`? In your example it isn't at all so you could just move it to afterwards and not have this problem, but I wonder if the real situation you are facing makes this impossible for some reason?

Comment: That may work, let me try it out .. .

Comment: it works ... visually it's not quite the same, i.e. I had a form with the border around it and the message was appearing inside the border.  Now the message appears outside of the border.  Still good enough for me though